# How do you make Jackson output Instant.MAX so that it is parsable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, jackson

JavaScript does not support dates greater than `9999-12-31`.  Is there a way through configuration that would make Jackson output and parse `Instant.MAX` as `9999-12-31-23:59.59.999999`  The standard output is `+1000000000-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z`

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you need this?

Comment: Would it be possible/acceptable for you to have your own class that inherits from `Instant` and overrides the `MAX` constant?

Comment: I'm trying to do it via configuration, rather than custom code that I implement on a per class level.